# why blur event not fire in react on textarea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

could you please tell me why blur event does not fire in react on textarea ?

actually, in my demo, I have one input and Textarea.i added blur event in both field . In the input field, it fired , but on textarea, it does not why?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-simple-example-xknkd

```
 <div>
            <Field
              name="myField"
              component={TextArea}
              name="operatingPinCode"
              placeholder="Operating Pincodes"
              label="Operating Pincodes"
              useCacheForDOMMeasurements
              format={() => console.log("ffhhh")}
              formatOnBlur
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't passed `onBlur` handler for `TextareaAutosize` in `textarea.js` file

```
<TextareaAutosize
  name={props.input.name}
  value={props.input.value}
  onChange={props.input.onChange}
/>
```

So you need to add it

```
<TextareaAutosize
  name={props.input.name}
  value={props.input.value}
  onChange={props.input.onChange}
  onBlur={props.input.onBlur}
/>
```